# how to control the video-element in the cloudinary-react Video component

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I want to call the .play() method on a cloudinary-react Video component.
I tried to put a ref onto the Video component, but when I call play on the ref it doesn't get forwarded to the video-tag.

`<Video ref={this.videoPlayer} />`

If I put a onClick on the component it gets forwarded to the video-tag and starts playing:

`<Video onClick={(e) => e.target.play()} />`

there is no interface on the video-component for playing or pausing or only no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To add controls to the video, a transformation can be added to the Cloudinary Video component. The transformation would be:

`<Transformation controls="true" />`

The video tag would look like this:

`<Video publicId="myPublicId" fallbackContent="Your browser does not support HTML5 video tags.">
  <Transformation controls="true"/>
</Video>`

You can also refer to this in the Cloudinary documentation here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_video_manipulation#example_3

Comment: I wonder if the documentation is up to date, I can set the controls attribute on the Video component and they show up, if I add a Transformation with controls="true" they are not shown. Anyway I don't want to show the controls, I want to add a custom centered play button and call the play() method to start the video. I need some way to access the video element api. For now I do it with findDOMNode()